# How to enable CORS for angularjs project running using gulp serve

Tags: angularjs, gulp, cors, ckeditor

I have an Angularjs project. I build it using gulp serve. I,m using ckeditor to uploade a file on remote server and i get this error:

```
Permission denied to access property "CKEDITOR" on cross-origin object
```

my gulp server.js file is as below

```
'use strict';

 var path = require('path');
 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var conf = require('./conf');
 var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
 var browserSyncSpa = require('browser-sync-spa');
 var util = require('util');
 var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');

 function  browserSyncInit(baseDir, browser) {
 browser = browser === undefined ? 'default' : browser;
 var routes = null;
 if(baseDir === conf.paths.src || (util.isArray(baseDir) && 
 baseDir.indexOf(conf.paths.src) !== -1)) {
    routes = {
      '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
    };
 }
 var server = {
   baseDir: baseDir,
   middleware: function (req, res, next) {
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS, POST, PUT');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'GET,OPTIONS, POST, PUT');
  next();
},
routes: routes
};

 browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
   startPath: '/',
   server: server,
   browser: browser,
   ghostMode: false
 });
}

 browserSync.use(browserSyncSpa({
    selector: '[ng-app]'// Only needed for angular apps
  }));

 gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], function () {
    browserSyncInit([path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'), conf.paths.src]);
    connect.server(server);
 });
gulp.task('serve:dist', ['build'], function () {
    browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist);
    connect.server(server);
 });
 gulp.task('serve:e2e', ['inject'], function () {
 browserSyncInit([conf.paths.tmp + '/serve', conf.paths.src], []);
 connect.server(server);
 });
 gulp.task('serve:e2e-dist', ['build'], function () {
   browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist, []);
   connect.server(server);
  });
```

but "Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'" did not set in header and i still get that error!

when page load Http response and request headers are as below:

response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    GET,OPTIONS, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Cache-Control   public, max-age=0
Last-Modified   Wed, 11 Oct 2017 05:56:16 GMT
ETag    W/"91a-15f0a01475b"
Date    Sat, 14 Oct 2017 05:03:02 GMT
Connection  keep-alive
```

request headers :

```
Host    localhost:3000
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Referer http://localhost:3000/
Cookie  language=fa; io=qkk4hCbXxaQ78a…FxfKICyH9dwHZOr5m2aJJ89Z0DS2H
Connection  keep-alive
If-Modified-Since   Wed, 11 Oct 2017 05:56:16 GMT
If-None-Match   W/"91a-15f0a01475b"
```

Thanks :)

I also used CORS Everywhere Firefox add-on. but it did not work

Comment: this has to be verified, but i think wildcard `*` is not supported for origin here. We had to do this recently and came to this: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || 'http://fallback-origin');` where "fallback-origin" was our server url in case origin was not set

Comment: @Kaddath
i checked it. it's not working yet. i also check request in wireshark and there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin parameter in header

Comment: in our case we also have this, maybe not relevant, but you can try: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type'); res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);`

Comment: @Kaddath it's not working yet :((

Comment: sorry, it's all i had.. is origin set when you do the request?

Comment: @Kaddath how can i confirm this?

Comment: if the request is sent from a browser, open the developper tools (before the request is made) and go to the "Network" section. You should see your request and by clicking on it you can see the details. If not, you'll have to log them.

Comment: @Kaddath when i open brows window in last http reguest , response headers are as below -->>> Access-Control-Allow-Origin 
*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers 
*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods 
GET,OPTIONS, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 
true
Accept-Ranges 
bytes
Cache-Control 
public, max-age=0
Last-Modified 
Wed, 11 Oct 2017 04:52:33 GMT
ETag 
W/"6e9-15f09c6f225"
content-length 
0
Date 
Wed, 11 Oct 2017 11:03:53 GMT
Connection 
keep-alive

Comment: infact my target headers are set but still i get error

Comment: these are the response headers (the ones you try to set right), you should also have the request headers (those emitted when doing the request), this is where you should look for the `origin` field. By the way, if you set `Allow-Origin` like in my example, you shouldn't get `*` as a response value, but your origin

Comment: @Kaddath there is no origin field in request header

Comment: you should try to set it explicitly when sending your request, it's easy to do

Comment: Can you see what response you get when browser sends the OPTIONS request. Your issue would definitely have error in console. Please add exact error message to console. Also when you say `ckeditor to upload a file on remote server`, which remote server are we talking about here?